# HIVE Get male and female count who opted for any course

Tags: sql, database, hive

I have two tables, students and training. Student and Training tables are as below.

```
Student
ID      name    age     sex     salary
1213    lavanya 18      Female  8000
1208    reshma  19      Female  14000
1207    bhavya  20      Female  15000
1212    Arshad  28      Male    20000
1209    kranthi 22      Male    22000
1210    Satish  24      Male    25000
1211    Krishna 25      Male    26000
1203    khaleel 34      Male    30000
1204    prasant 30      Male    31000
1206    laxmi   25      Female  35000
1205    kiran   20      Male    40000
1201    gopal   45      Male    50000
1202    manisha 40      Female  51000

Training
1       1201    csharp
2       1205    c
3       1201    c
4       1202    java
5       1205    java
6       1203    shell
7       1204    hadoop
8       1201    hadoop
```

Now I want count of males and females who have joined any course.
I tried below query-

```
hive> select s.sex, count(*) from student join training t on s.id=t.sid group by s.sex;
```

But this query is giving output as Female 2 Male 4
Though expected outcome should be Female 1 Male 2
Please note this is a sample and short form of data being used.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your query, but - returns the result you mentioned (1 female, 2 male). If possible, post your own SQL*Plus copy/paste session (take my example) so that we'd see what you exactly did).

```
SQL> with student (id, name, sex) as
  2    (select 1, 'alex', 'm' from dual union
  3     select 2, 'rita', 'f' from dual union
  4     select 3, 'max',  'm' from dual union
  5     select 4, 'steve', 'm' from dual
  6    ),
  7  training (id, sid, course) as
  8    (select 1, 2, 'java' from dual union
  9     select 2, 3, 'c' from dual union
 10     select 3, 1, 'java' from dual
 11    )
 12  select s.sex, count(*)
 13  from student s join training t on t.sid = s.id
 14  group by s.sex;

S   COUNT(*)
- ----------
m          2
f          1
```

Comment: I have updated question with exact data I am using, Please see if this can help. Is it possible that only in HIVE this query doesn't work?

Comment: "Exact data" is, in this case, irrelevant (at least, I think so - sample data was fine. It doesn't matter whether it is "Alex" or "Arshad"). As far as I can tell, this is a simple query and *should* work OK.

Comment: :) right. I thought may be number of course per person is affecting it. If it works in all other DBs, I guess problem might be in hive related settings.

Answer (score 0):

I try in MySQL and in Oracle, and this query is OK.

```
SELECT S.sex, count(*) 
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN training T on S.id = T.sid 
GROUP BY S.sex;
```

RESULT, female = 1, male = 2

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is a simple count by gender, why not use

```
    select sex, count(*)
    from student
    group by sex
    order by sex
```

Comment: need to check in training table also, who have opted for any course

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
select s.sex, count(*)
from students s
where exists (select 1 from training t where t.sid = s.id);
```

The problem with `join` is that it counts each student based on the number of trainings they are in.

Answer (score 0):

**Here i had written a code taking your data:-**

```
SELECT 
    final.ct_sex as sex,count(*) as num
FROM 
    (SELECT tb.sex as ct_sex FROM newschema.mytable AS tb JOIN (SELECT tr.ID,GROUP_CONCAT(tr.skill) as skills FROM newschema.train AS tr GROUP BY tr.ID) AS tp ON tb.ID = tp.ID) as final
group by
    final.ct_sex
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why join fails here, Below subquery is giving correct output though.
 select sex, count(*) from salary where salary.id in (select sid from training) group by salary.sex;